# How do I check to see if my computer is infected with the OSX/Crisis Trojan?

Tags: macos, malware

Just recently, [a new trojan for OS X](http://nvonews.com/2012/07/26/at-the-time-of-os-x-mountain-lion-launch-new-mac-trojan-found/) was discovered. Apparently it only affects Snow Leopard and Lion. Whether it does/doesn't affect Mountain Lion is still unknown. The trojan sits on your computer and hides, doing nothing so far. How do I check to see if this trojan has been installed on my system? If it is, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [Intego has been investigating this trojan](http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/new-apple-mac-trojan-called-osxcrisis-discovered-by-intego-virus-team/) and has found that the trojan will only be on your machine if the following folder exists:

`/Library/ScriptingAdditions/appleHID/`

If it was installed with admin privileges, this files/folders will exist:

- `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/XPCServices/`
- `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.mdworker_server.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.mdworker_server`
- `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.mdworker_server.xpc/Contents/Resources/`
- `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/appleHID/Contents/Resources/appleOsax.r`

These files ping the IP address 176.58.100.37 every 5 minutes. It currently doesn't do anything, but at any point the trojan could activate and potentially cause problems. Intego also reports that Mountain Lion is not affected by the trojan. Intego's VirusBarrier will remove the trojan.

Comment: The existence of `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/XPCServices/` does not indicate whether you have this trojan: its a normal directory and is part of the well-documented XPC Services API.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Okay, but according to Intego, that is a part of the trojan. Did you read the article?

Comment: I did; I'm saying they're oversimplifying/mischaracterizing the nature of that directory: its mere existence does not indicate you have OSX/Crisis. I found [Kaspersky Lab's account of the trojan](https://www.securelist.com/en/blog/719/New_malware_for_Mac_Backdoor_OSX_Morcut) to be more accurate/measured.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Just a note on the article you linked to; it says the name of the malware is "Backdoor.OSX.Morcut". Intego labels it as "OS/X Crisis" Is this the same piece of malware?

Comment: Yeah: [OSX/Crisis is Intego's name, Backdoor.OSX.Morcut is Kaspersky's name](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/07/mac-spying-malware/).